# Odoo - page number in qweb reports

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, qwebview

I am working with qweb reports in odoo 10 . Here is what i did

```xml
<odoo>
<template id="report_customer">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-set="data_report_margin_top" t-value="50"/>
        <t t-foreach="range(5)" t-as="1">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                <div class="page example-css-class">
                    <h2>Report title</h2>
                    <p>This object's name is
                        <span t-field="o.full_name"/>
                    </p>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                         <li>Page:</li>
                         <li><span class="page"/></li>
                         <li>/</li>
                         <li><span class="topage"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

and i also tried this

```xml
<odoo>
<template id="report_customer">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-set="data_report_margin_top" t-value="50"/>
        <t t-foreach="range(5)" t-as="1">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                <div class="page example-css-class">
                    <h2>Report title</h2>
                    <p>This object's name is
                        <span t-field="o.full_name"/>
                    </p>
                    <div class="footer" style="text-align: center !important;">
                      Page  <span class="page"/> of <span class="topage"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

but in both cases i am not able to see page numbers. I also tried adding custom header and footer in separate templates but that also doesn't work.

Comment: I think it will be related with the css, does Page: is printed on sheet

Comment: The first problem is that footer is inside the page:
<div class="page">
     <!-- your code -->
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <!-- your code -->
</div>

Comment: Yes in printing on sheet without any issue, also i tried putting it after the `page` div.

Comment: Do you need to use `report.internal_layout`? Use `report.external_layout`, pages already appear by default on the footer

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row">
     <center><span>Page </span><span class="page" /> of <span class="topage" /></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly for me.

**Note :** I have used without calling `report.external_layout`

Answer (score 1):

- Please try this code for page number in Qweb-report. It will automatically display page no.

  `<t t-call="report.external_layout"></t>`